# material ui table row checkbox not displaying

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have created a table using material UI for my react app in a separate file.

TradesTable.js

```
const DummyTableRow = (props) => {
    let myRows = props.trades.map((trade, index) => {
        return <TableRow>
        <TableRowColumn key={index} style={{fontSize:'10px'}}>{trade[0]}</TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn key={index} style={{fontSize:'10px'}}>{trade[1]}</TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn key={index} style={{fontSize:'10px'}}>{trade[2]}</TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn key={index} style={{fontSize:'10px'}}>{trade[3]}</TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn key={index} style={{fontSize:'10px'}}>{trade[4]}</TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn key={index} style={{fontSize:'10px'}}>{trade[5]}</TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn key={index} style={{fontSize:'10px'}}>{trade[6]}</TableRowColumn>
        </TableRow>
        });
    return myRows;
}

const TradesTable = (props) => {
    return(
        <Table>
            <TableHeader>
                <TableRow>
                    <TableHeaderColumn>Trade date</TableHeaderColumn>
                    <TableHeaderColumn>Commodity</TableHeaderColumn>
                    <TableHeaderColumn>Side</TableHeaderColumn>
                    <TableHeaderColumn>Qty</TableHeaderColumn>
                    <TableHeaderColumn>Price</TableHeaderColumn>
                    <TableHeaderColumn>CounterParty</TableHeaderColumn>
                    <TableHeaderColumn>Location</TableHeaderColumn>
                </TableRow>
            </TableHeader>
        <TableBody>
            <DummyTableRow trades={props.trades}/>
        </TableBody>
    </Table>
    );
}

module.exports = TradesTable
```

The rows of this table are being populated from the props of the component.

This table is being used in some other component as part of a material UI `<AppBar>` component.

```
<AppBar style={{backgroundColor: 'White'}} 
                    iconElementLeft={<TradesTable trades={this.props.trade}/>} 
                    ....
                    ....
```

The value for `this.props.trade` is coming from the store.

The problem here is that the table header shows the checkbox, but the rows dont show the checkbox
I have read the documentation and the default behavior is that the checkboxes show up.

Wham I am doing here that the checkbox for the rows don't show up?

[image]

Comment: checkboxes should be there by default. Are there any errors in the console ? Can you try to add selectable={true} to the <Table> element ?

Comment: There are no errors in the console, I tried manually setting all the attributes related to checkboxes as true, still it did not work.

Comment: Can you try removing `DummyTableRow` and inserting the rows directly ? or instead of `<DummyTableRow trades={props.trades}/>`, use `{DummyTableRow(props.trades)}` ?

Comment: did you set the 'displayRowCheckbox' to true at the TableBody?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here issue is with `DummyTableRow` :

What happens When you try to do :

```
<TableBody>
   <DummyTableRow trades={props.trades}/>
</TableBody>
```

What it does is

```
<TableBody>
   <DummyTableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <TableRowColumn key={index} style={{fontSize:'10px'}}>{trade[0]}</TableRowColumn>
            ...
        </TableRow>
        ...
   <DummyTableRow>
</TableBody>
```

That is not quite correct structure , it should be like

```
<TableBody>
    <TableRow>
        <TableRowColumn key={index} style={{fontSize:'10px'}}>{trade[0]}</TableRowColumn>
        ...
    </TableRow>
    ...
</TableBody>
```

> Solution for this :

Creat a simple function instead of stateless Component that

```
const getRow = (data) => {
    let myRows = data.trades.map((trade, index) => {
        return <TableRow>
        <TableRowColumn key={index} style={{fontSize:'10px'}}>{trade[0]}</TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn key={index} style={{fontSize:'10px'}}>{trade[1]}</TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn key={index} style={{fontSize:'10px'}}>{trade[2]}</TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn key={index} style={{fontSize:'10px'}}>{trade[3]}</TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn key={index} style={{fontSize:'10px'}}>{trade[4]}</TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn key={index} style={{fontSize:'10px'}}>{trade[5]}</TableRowColumn>
        <TableRowColumn key={index} style={{fontSize:'10px'}}>{trade[6]}</TableRowColumn>
        </TableRow>
        });
    return myRows;
}
```

And use it like

```
<TableBody>
   { getRow(props.trades) }
</TableBody>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-material-table-row)** (With issue and solution both)

Comment: This works!!! got another issue, which I will try to resolve. Thanks!!!

Comment: @AmarDev, Glad to here that :)